# how to sum values in excel until they reach a specified total, then add the cell next in the column

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I want to have a threshold value in one cell (`A1`) and take it as a reference for adding cells.

Suppose I have

```
A1 - 10
A2 - 4
A3 - 2
A4 - 3
A5 - 4
A6 - 6
```

I want to add cells based on A1(Threshold).

If `A1` is 10, it would add `A2:A5`, sum = 13
If `A1` is 9, it would add `A2:A4`, sum = 9

The SUM formula is

```
=SUM(OFFSET($A$2,0,0,MAX(INDEX((SUBTOTAL(9,OFFSET($A$2, 0,0,ROW(1:99),1))<$A$1)*ROW(1:99),,))+1,1))
```

I have a formula for this first part part...

Then I want the formula to add a percentage of the value in the next cell after the threshold has been reached:

If `A1` is 10 then cells from `A2:A5` should be added, plus 50% of `A6`; sum = 16

Answer (score 2):

The *simplest* way to do this would be to use an indirect on that cell the way you've already found it -

```
=SUM(OFFSET($A$2,0,0,MAX(INDEX((SUBTOTAL(9,OFFSET($A$2, 0,0,ROW(1:99),1))
<$A$1)*ROW(1:99),,))+1,1),
(0.5)*INDIRECT("A"&MAX(INDEX((SUBTOTAL(9,OFFSET($A$2,0,0,ROW(1:99),1))  
<$A$1)*ROW(1:99),,))+3))
```

I think the second part could be better or work off of the first part, but I haven't figured it out yet.