# How to sum values in excel until they reach a specified sum

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I want to have a threshold value in one cell (A1) and take it as a reference for adding cells.

Suppose I have

A1 - 10

A2 - 4

A3 - 2

A4 - 3

A5 - 4

A6 - 6

I want to add cells based on A1(Threshold).

If A1 is 10, it would add A2:A5, sum = 13

If A1 is 9, it would add A2:A4, sum = 9

The SUM formula is

```excel
=SUM(OFFSET($A$2,0,0,MAX(INDEX((SUBTOTAL(9,OFFSET($A$2, 0,0,ROW(1:5),1))<$A$1)*ROW(1:5),,))+1,1))
```

But I have a problem when the sum cannot be reached in interval set in the ROW formula.

In this example, if you set ROW to ROW(1:5) and set A1 to 14, you will get 19. So the formula keeps adding even when max ROW is reached.

How can I stop this?

/Asger

Comment: Just thinking aloud here (might not be 100% correct), but what about using logic similar to *=if(SUM(A2:A5)>A1, A1, SUM(A2:A5:))* ?

Comment: Dosen't work - because I want it to stop when it reaches the value i A1. So if A1 is 3 it stops at at the value in A2 which is 4. In your case it would say 3 (A1).

Comment: Ah so it can exceed the value in A1, but not add any further cells? Is there only 6 rows?

Comment: The 'rules' aren't exactly clear here, but I think my approach would be a helper column with the sums in (hide if needed) and an `INDEX` `MATCH` with the exact parameter of `MATCH` set to 1. That might work.

Comment: Also, how bizarre - the first half of this question is a word for word duplicate (including sample data and formula) of a question almost 4 years old. https://superuser.com/questions/1067065/how-to-sum-values-in-excel-until-they-reach-a-specified-total-then-add-the-cell

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to sum values in excel until they reach a specified total, then add the cell next in the column](https://superuser.com/questions/1067065/how-to-sum-values-in-excel-until-they-reach-a-specified-total-then-add-the-cell)

Comment: @AlexM That is scary!! Although I see your 4 yr old Question, and raise you [this 5 yr old one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26274633/add-numbers-until-value-reached?rq=1) (albeit from a different stack)

Comment: @Smock this must be some oddly persistent homework question from somewhere.

Comment: @AlexM or some almost self-aware AI about to take over the world, but just needs to be able to do this function in Excel before it can realise it's evil plan.

Comment: @Smock we've been judging Microsoft tech writers too harshly for all these years - the fact that their written documentation is impenetrable to machine learning has actually saved us from the singularity many times over!

Comment: I found the old one by googesearch, but it dosen't work - hence my question. I found it easy just to copy-paste. The sum (x) >= A1. It should stop when the sum is equal or greater than A1. But why does it exceed ROW(1:5), how do I stop it??

Answer (score 0):

If you only have `A1` as threshold and then 5 cells with value, you could use this formula in `A7`

```
=IF(A2>=A1,A2,IF(SUM(A2:A3)>=A1,SUM(A2:A3),IF(SUM(A2:A4)>=A1,SUM(A2:A4),IF(SUM(A2:A5)>=A1,SUM(A2:A5),SUM(A2:A6)))))
```

It's not very elegant (and not feasibly scalable to much larger sets of data) 
but should do the trick

It does behave as requested in the OP as it stands right now (13 or 9)

Comment: Thanks, that would work and it works in my current excel but in my real excel work I have over 5.000 lines, and more than 10 sheets and that is very heavy, so I am looking for something more smooth.